# Login into a php-website and webscrape website using python without selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I am trying to login to this website `https://www.icloudemserp.com/tpct/` for scraping some data but I am unable to login. I was trying it with requests in python, using get to get the URL and post to send the post URL and the form data. It just doesn't work or either I don't understand it.

I know how I can achieve this with selenium. The website only posts to this website after I log in `https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/checkuser1.php` and this is the form data:

```
[General][1]
[Form data][2]
form data:
branchid: 1
userid:****
pass_word:***
branchid: 17
sel_acad_yr: 2013-2014
sel_sem: Sem 1
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
login_data = {
    'branchid':'1',
    'userid':'****',
    'pass_word':'***',
    'branchid':'17',
    'sel_acad_yr': '2013-2014',
    'sel_sem': 'Sem1',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.icloudemserp.com/tpct/'
    r = s.get(url)
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

    r = s.post('https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/checkuser1.php', data=login_data)
    print(r.content)
```

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: well, you have to show us your `code` as we couldn't expect your code !

Comment: Sorry for that, I used to use the code for scraping codechef and it does work. I have added the code above. Thanks for helping.